# How to prevent HTML entity encoding in Drupal attribute objects?

Tags: theming

Is there an easy way to disable the HTML entity encoding of CSS class names?

When I create CSS classes with ampersands or the "larger than" symbol (which might look strange but is technically valid in CSS classes) like this

```
{% set my_attribute_object = create_attribute({'class': '[&>span]:text-red'}) %}
<div {{ my_attribute_object }}>
  I'm text in <span>red</span> color.
</div>
```

it renders escaped entities like

```
<div class="[&amp;&gt;span]:text-red">
  I'm text in <span>red</span> color.
</div>
```

which then breaks the TailwindCSS JIT compiler, who expects real ampersands in the HTML source.

I could do something like this

```
<div {{ my_attribute_object|replace({'&amp;': '&', '&gt;': '>'})|raw }}>
```

but I need to render attribute objects in Twig templates all the time, and adding this all the time is ugly and tedious. I'm looking for a better way (maybe a preprocess function that does the |replace|raw automatically for every attribute?)

Comment: You need to extend the Attribute object overriding [createAttributeValue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/function/Attribute%3A%3AcreateAttributeValue/10) to not convert HTML markup but to put it in a AttributeMarkup object (that you also need to extend from AttributeValueBase and adjust the magic string method). Then use the new Attribute class in preprocess.

Comment: or to be more precise not only in preprocess, whenever you want to add attributes with HTML markup first convert the existing attributes `$attributes = new MyMarkupAttribute($attributes);`

Comment: I wished attribute objects would be a symfony service... I guess I've to dig through all my modules :/